# Prevent pod deletion by the garbage collector

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

It seems that kubernetes tends to delete the orphan pods automatically when the node is `NotReady` for some time, if the terminated pod amount is up to the threshold.

The imps might be the Garbage Collector, or the [Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-lifetime):

> In general, Pods do not disappear until someone destroys them. This might be a human or a controller. The only exception to this rule is that Pods with a phase of Succeeded or Failed for more than some duration (determined by the master) will expire and be automatically destroyed.

After appending the `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold=-1` to the controller manager, the pods will be retained for a period of time after the node is `NotReady`, but it was removed at last.

Then I'm trying to config the Garbage Collector. Actually, there's a `Deployment` in my cluster, with the `ownerReferences` defined as following, but how to specify the owner for bare pods, in order to prevent pods deletion when the nodes are `NotReady`?

```
ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: cluster-autoscaler-8253924875
    uid: 930abce3-58c8-4738-b891-8653ae71c2d1
```